# Load a specified column in DataGridView with values from a database

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have a database with a table. What I want to do is programatically load values from a column of the table to a column of the DataGridView.

I have a table "Actions", with a field "Total", which has some data: 10, 20, 35, 50, etc.
I want to put this field into the DataGridView in the 2nd column.

So the DataGridView should look like this.(the other columns are already set).

```
| Name       | Total       | Something    |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| adsad      |       10    |     This     |
| sddssdf    |       20    |    column    |
| name1      |       35    |     will     |
| name       |       50    |      be      |
| nmas       |        1    |    center    |
| gjghjhh    |       67    |   aligned    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the particular column in Gridview and try following code :

```
DataGridView dataGridView2 = new DataGridView();
BindingSource bindingSource2 = new BindingSource();

dataGridView2.ColumnCount = 2;

dataGridView2.Columns[0].Name = "FieldOne";
dataGridView2.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "FieldOne";
dataGridView2.Columns[1].Name = "FieldTwo";
dataGridView2.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "FieldTwo";

bindingSource1.DataSource = GetDataTable();
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add a new column to your `DataTable` and then bind it to your `DataGridView`.

```
//call SQL helper class to get initial data 
DataTable dt = sql.ExecuteDataTable("sp_MyProc");

dt.Columns.Add("NewColumn", typeof(System.Int32));

foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    //need to set value to NewColumn column
    row["NewColumn"] = 0;   // or set it to some other value
}

// possibly save your Dataset here, after setting all the new values
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: I have to set the columns vales equal to the field's value of each record. So, if I have a table of which's records have the values: 10, 20, 35 etc. for the field "Total", I have to copy that field into the column in dataGridView.